# Converting std::strings to WCHAR* and char*

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion, filepath

I am trying to create a resource manager that tells you where a file is based on a key word. I am trying to implement it into my Directx11 programming code, but I've run into some problems. The code calls for `WCHAR*` and `char*` file paths. I have the file path written in an std::string format.

```
char* ResourceManager::getFilePathCHAR(string reference){
    string location;
    //looks through a file and gives the folder
    location = parser(reference);
    string result;
    //adds the other stuff like c:// ........../image.png
    result = appender(location, reference);
    m_filePathChar = new char[result.length() + 1]; ////--|
    strcpy(m_filePathChar, result.c_str());         ////--|-> part im looking at
    return m_filePathChar;                          ////--|
}
```

The problem with this is that the other information ive been reading on have told me that return pointers like this is bad, so i just want to know if theres a better way to do this? Also, how do i convert `std::string` to `WCHAR*`. I am probably not looking hard enough but the majority of places I've checked have given me infromation on `wchar_t`. I am still relatively new to pointers, so im not sure about the exact rules on what you can and can't do. Thanks for the help and input.

Comment: `WCHAR` is just a typedef for `wchar_t`; your references for `wchar_t` conversion should apply.

Comment: Returning dynamically allocated arrays is asking for memory leaks.

Comment: In your case it is better to make **m_filePathChar** **std::string** as well and just return **m_filePathChar.c_str()**. For converting **wchar_t** - convert **string** to **wsrting** and use **c_str()** again.

Comment: @MucgaekNastenko oh okay i see, so i just return the string and then i convert it into a pointer later?